# Page numbering in Footer is lost while converting to PDF with Docx4j

Tags: java, xhtml, docx, docx4j

Im Building a API to convert XHtml Files in Word files (.docx) and in PDF, using the Docx4j Libary.
At this Moment the Application works almost well with a few little (i think) formatting issues.

I add CTSimpleFields to my Word document using this code snippet:

```
 CTSimpleField currentPageNumber = factory.createCTSimpleField();
 currentPageNumber.setInstr(" PAGE \\* Arabic  \\* MERGEFORMAT ");
 CTSimpleField totalPageCount = factory.createCTSimpleField();
 totalPageCount.setInstr("NUMPAGES  \\* Arabic  \\* MERGEFORMAT");
```

This works well if the document is saved as docx

```
wordZipFile.save(getOutputStream());
```

[Word Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR50c.png)

But when i try to convert the WordMLPackage to PDF using this snippet:

```
FieldUpdater updater = new FieldUpdater(this.wordZipFile);
updater.update(true);
Docx4J.toPDF(this.wordZipFile,this.getOutputStream());
```

The page numbering is missing in the output PDF file.

[PDF Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmk8w.png)

Has somebody an idea how to workaround for this problem?

Comment: Which approach to converting to PDF are you using? See https://www.docx4java.org/blog/2020/09/office-pptxxlsxdocx-to-pdf-to-in-docx4j-8-2-3/

Comment: Im currently using the FO impl. because the documents should not leave the Company Servers, and documents4j local, is no option because the converter service runs on a linux machine.

Comment: @JasonPlutext Any Idea to solve the Problem?